# Typing national characters in a slightly different way

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

Typical way of typing national characters (if you need to use them) on a keyboard looks as follows:

*This is an example for Polish `ą` character:*

1. Push `ALT`.
2. Push `a`.
3. Release `a`.

As a result we 'll see `ą` on the screen.

Now, the **question**: I am looking for slightly more convenient solution:

1. Push and release `ALT`.
2. Push and release `a`.

As a result we 'll see `ą` on the screen as well.

I can easily configure emacs to behave like this. Do you know any hack/software or whatever which could allow me to use keyboard in all Mac applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky Keys will do that.

System Prefs > Accessibility > Keyboard

It removes the need to hold a modifier key before pressing the associated key to be modified.

[image]

You can set options to make it switchable, beep when used, or display the modifier on-screen

[image]